# Find out what is causing problem in IIS7

Tags: c#, web-applications, iis-7

We have a C# web application, and the latest deploy doesn't work on our Windows Small Business Server 2008 (IIS7). The exact copy of that site runs fine on my Windows 7 machine (IIS7.5). The previous version and other builds still work on the Server 2008 R2 machine, but this itteration doesn't.

I've checked the W3SVC logs, but no requests are logged. I've checked the eventlog for errors, but no errors are logged. I also checked in fiddler, but the request just doesn't get a response as far as I can tell (Result column remains -)

When you open the url, the browser will just keep loading (no timeout).

Is there anything else I can check or enable to debug this IIS7 behaviour?

Thanks in advance,

Nick.

**UPDATE**

I published the application again & created a new site in IIS, and this new version works. While my the immediate problem is solved at this time, I would still like to know how to debug IIS7, see how it works & why it would keep loading infinitely.

Comment: Have you tried attaching a debugger to the IIS process? Check MSDN for [resources on remote debugging](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y7f5zaaa.aspx).

Comment: Just did that, if I open the website via a file share, Visual Studio locks up :-/

Comment: Is this a regular web application, WCF service, or what?

Comment: First 6 words: "We have a C# web application"...

Comment: Just an FYI: 2008 R2 runs 7.5; just like Windows 7.

Comment: You should get a more explicit error message if it were this, but just in case: you didn't upgrade to .NET 4 in this new version by chance? Also, what did you mean by "if I open the website via a file share"?

Comment: Nope, no upgrade, only thing I changed was upload a new version of a web app (we run 6x the same web app on the same machine). As for the IIS version: I'm afraid I have mispoken; it's a SBS 2008, not a R2, my bad (with IIS7). The open via file share related to the remote debugging of the website, tried that, but didn't go anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

First, I would drop a regular .html file into the sites directory.  Then I would have a browser request that specific static file.  This would bypass the .net engine and should be logged.

If for some reason it doesn't work and/or isn't logged then there are other things to check, let us know.

Assuming that it does serve the file and you are pointing to the correct machine then inspect your global.asax file and remove any type of error handling you might have.  Also turn off the custom errors section of your web.config.  Both of which could result in the server essentially spinning off into nothingness if improperly coded.  If you have any type of additional threads you are spinning up on access, then see if you can turn those off or add additional logging.

Next, look in the HTTPERR logs to see if you can identify what's going on.  These are located at
%SystemRoot%\system32\LogFiles\HTTPERR\httperr*.log

Info about this log file is at: http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;en-us;820729

Comment: Thanks, first helpfull commment :) I tried that, it has the same behaviour. I'll try creating a new IIS site with the same folder as a target. Hmm, new website to same folder doesn't work, keeps having the same issue.

Comment: The HttpErr log file didn't have any relevant errors (only Exchange AutoDiscover.xml messages)

Comment: @NKCSS: Just to be clear: you dropped an html file into the folder on this site, requested it, and couldn't get a response OR a log message and httperr had nothing related?

Comment: @NKCSS: I would suggest that you might do a hard drive integrity scan.  Sounds like something is possibly corrupted either in the metabase or in those directory entries.

Comment: Did a full scan with HDTune, HDD is ok.

Answer (score 0):

If your app uses ADO then there is chance that depending where the build occurred on Windows 7 or not and whether SP1 is installed or not (at the time of the build) that your build is broken by some Micorsoft ADO-update contained in SP1 (see http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/225491/Your-ADO-is-broken.aspx).

Comment: Not using ADO, sorry. The application hasn't changed in a fundimental way, multiple versions of that same web app still work on that machine.

Answer (score 0):

If no requests are logged in the W3SVC logs then it probably means that IIS is not recieving the request at all - likely due to firewall configuration or similar.

You should diagnose why IIS is unavailable (for example by attempting to serve some static content) and then try again.

Comment: It's not the firewall, other versions of the same web app (and other sites) still work and this worked before upgrading. I am looking for a way to debug IIS7, see how it handles this request to see where it goes wrong.\

Answer (score 0):

Try these:

- re-register asp.net runtime with your IIS7
- make sure the asp.net extension for the correct version is set to Allowed in  'ISAPI and CGI restrictions' in your IIS

Comment: Multiple versions of this app & other ASP.NET applications still work, only the files were replaced, the site config has worked this morning and the weeks before that.